# Get two forms to display inline

Tags: html, css

This doesnt work

```
<form style ='display:inline;'>
 <input type = 'submit'/>
</form>
<form style ='display:inline;'>
  <input type = 'submit'/>
</form>
```

I want two forms that submit to different scripts and  each have an input button to display inline.

I want to style it inline as someone else will make more permanent changes to the main CSS file what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think what you want is to display them side by side. You can do it using floats instead like so:

```
<form style ='float: left; padding: 5px;'>
akjfhdkjahj<br />
 <input type = 'submit'/>
</form>
<form style ='float: left; padding: 5px;'>
  aklfjas<br />
  <input type = 'submit'/>
</form>
```

But even that's not ideal. What would be best is to wrap each < form > in < div >s and use float in the div tag instead.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand the question correctly, you can use `display:inline-block;`

```
form{
    width:200px;           //JUST FOR SHOW
    height:200px;          //JUST FOR SHOW
    background:red;        //JUST FOR SHOW
    display:inline-block;  
    margin:1em;            
}
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/dn5NQ/3/

Obviously, you will need to rework the content of the forms... as you say.

Comment: in opera display:inline-block for form causes what do yo call sweet Jesus... Bad idea

Comment: this is better than float:left because it lets you center the forms.

Answer (score 2):

Just use, **display:inline-block** . Example:

```html
<form style ='display:inline-block;'>
 <input type = 'submit'/>
</form>
<form style ='display:inline-block;'>
  <input type = 'submit'/>
</form>
```

And you may also use HTML Table to do this forcefully. Example:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
     <td>
       <form>
         <input type="submit" />
       </form>
     </td>
     <td>
       <form>
         <input type="submit" />
       </form>
     </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

> an input button to display inline

If the buttons should be displayed inline, then you need to assign those styles to the inputs, not to the forms.

Answer (score 0):

You should use quotes `"` for your attributes, and style the buttons `inline` as well as they are defined as `block` by default.